# Prefix sum find max collect value by moving in array in m moves

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to implement the prefix sum logic in php [codility](https://codility.com/media/train/3-PrefixSums.pdf).

Here is the problem that I'm trying to solve:

> You are given a non-empty, zero-indexed array A of n (1 ¬ n ¬ 100 000)
>   integers a0, a1, . . . , an−1 (0 ¬ ai ¬ 1 000). This array represents
>   number of mushrooms growing on the consecutive spots along a road. You
>   are also given integers k and m (0 ¬ k, m < n). A mushroom picker is
>   at spot number k on the road and should perform m moves. In one move
>   she moves to an adjacent spot. She collects all the mushrooms growing
>   on spots she visits. The goal is to calculate the maximum number of
>   mushrooms that the mushroom picker can collect in m moves. For
>   example, consider array A such that: [2, 3, 7, 5, 1, 3, 9]
>
> The mushroom picker starts at spot k = 4 and should perform m = 6
>   moves. She might move to spots 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and thereby collect 1
>   + 5 + 7 + 3 + 9 = 25 mushrooms. This is the maximal number of mushrooms she can collect.

Here's my code in php:

```
$P = [2, 3, 7, 5, 1, 3, 9]; // mushroom count per position
$k = 4; // start position of picker
$m = 6; // moves allowed
$n = count($P);
$result = 0;
$pref = $this->getPrefixSum($P);

$leftBoundary = min($m, $k);

for ($i=0; $i < $leftBoundary; $i++) { 
        $leftPos  = $k - $i;
        $rightPos = min($n - 1, max($k, $k + $m - 2 * $i));
        $result   = max($result, $pref[$rightPos] - $pref[$leftPos]);
    }

    $rightBoundary = min($m + 1, $n - $k);
    for ($i=0; $i < $rightBoundary ; $i++) { 
        $rightPos = $k + $i;
        $leftPos  = max(0, min($k, $k - ($m - 2 * $i)));
        $result   = max($result, $pref[$rightPos] - $pref[$leftPos]);
    }

function getPrefixSum($A)
{
    $prefixSums = array();
    $prefixSums[0] = $A[0];
    for ($i=1; $i < count($A); $i++) { 
        $prefixSums[$i] = $prefixSums[$i - 1] + $A[$i];
    }
    return $prefixSums;
}
```

Unfortunately, I am getting a result of **19** only (**Expected answer was 25**). Do you guys have any idea if I'm missing anything? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The best result should be chosen from traversals covering cell k, R right and L left cells where `R+2*L=m` or `L+2*R=m` (with border conditions). Does your code account for all these variants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple mistakes translating the code from the example. The primary problem is that your `prefixSum` function is producing an array with one less index than the example code. Here's a comparison:

```
# them
[0, 2, 5, 12, 17, 18, 21, 30] 

# you
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 12
    [3] => 17
    [4] => 18
    [5] => 21
    [6] => 30
)
```

Otherwise, you've omitted operations that they included, so I'll highlight them in the working code below:

```
function getPrefixSum($A) {
    $prefixSums = [0];
                # ^^^

    for ($i = 1; $i < count($A) + 1; $i++) { 
                             # ^^^^
        $prefixSums[$i] = $prefixSums[$i-1] + $A[$i-1];
                                                 # ^^
    }

    return $prefixSums;
}

$P = [2, 3, 7, 5, 1, 3, 9]; // mushroom count per position
$k = 4; // start position of picker
$m = 6; // moves allowed
$n = count($P);
$result = 0;
$pref = getPrefixSum($P);

$leftBoundary = min($m, $k) + 1;
                         # ^^^^

for ($i = 0; $i < $leftBoundary; $i++) { 
    $leftPos = $k - $i;
    $rightPos = min($n - 1, max($k, $k + $m - 2 * $i));
    $result = max($result, $pref[$rightPos+1] - $pref[$leftPos]);
                                        # ^^
}

$rightBoundary = min($m + 1, $n - $k);

for ($i = 0; $i < $rightBoundary; $i++) { 
    $rightPos = $k + $i;
    $leftPos = max(0, min($k, $k - ($m - 2 * $i)));
    $result = max($result, $pref[$rightPos+1] - $pref[$leftPos]); 
                                        # ^^
}

echo "$result\n";
```

Output:

```
25
```

[Try it out](https://repl.it/@ggorlen/QuestionableCumbersomeAssemblylanguage).

Comment: A really dumb mistake on my end. Great catch, thanks man! I appreciate you pointing out the differences.

Comment: Not a problem. Their code and explanation is fairly dense and not particularly easy to follow without some eye strain.